# I am trying to add in collision but it isn't working

Tags: python, pygame, collision

```
import pygame
import os,sys
import random
import math

img_path = os.path.join("punch.png")
img_blob = os.path.join("blob.png")

class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super(Enemy,self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([160,160])
        self.image.set_colorkey(black)
        self.image.blit(pygame.image.load(img_blob),(0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.speed = 2
    def move_towards_player(self,character):
        dx,dy = character.rect.x - self.rect.x,character.rect.y - self.rect.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx,dy)
        dx,dy = dx / dist,dy / dist
        self.rect.x += dx * self.speed
        self.rect.y += dy * self.speed
    def draw(self,surface):

        surface.blit(self.image,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y))
class character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x = 275, y = 250):

        super(character,self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([160,160])
        self.image.set_colorkey(black)
        self.image.blit(pygame.image.load(img_path),(0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x

        self.rect.y = y



    def movement(self):

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        dist = 10

        if key[pygame.K_w]:

            self.rect.y -= dist

        elif key[pygame.K_s]:

            self.rect.y += dist

        if key[pygame.K_a]:

            self.rect.x -= dist

        elif key[pygame.K_d]:

            self.rect.x += dist


        if self.rect.x > 1110:

            self.rect.x = 1110

        if self.rect.y < 20:

            self.rect.y = 20

        elif self.rect.y > 710:

            self.rect.y = 710
        if self.rect.x <20:
            self.rect.x = 20
        elif self.rect.x == 1110 and self.rect.y > 300 and self.rect.y < 400:
            self.rect.x = 25
        if self.rect.y == 20 and self.rect.x >500 and self.rect.x < 600:
            self.rect.y = 715
        elif self.rect.x == 20 and self.rect.y > 300 and self.rect.y < 400:
            self.rect.x = 1090
        if self.rect.y == 710 and self.rect.x >500 and self.rect.x < 600:
            self.rect.y = 25

# top of left and right doors are y = 220, bottom of left and right doors are y = 240 # right side of top and bottom doors are x = 285, left of top and bottom doors are x = 260
def collide(self,enemy,enemy_list):
    if self.rect.colliderect(enemy.rect):
        enemy_list.remove(enemy)

def draw(self,surface):

    surface.blit(self.image,(self.rect.x,self.rect.y))






pygame.init()                               # Pygame is initialised (starts running)

players = pygame.sprite.Group()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1250,850]) # Set the width and height of the screen [width,height]

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")       # Name your window

background_image = pygame.image.load("untilted.png")


done = False                                # Loop until the user clicks the close button.

clock = pygame.time.Clock()                 # Used to manage how fast the screen updates

black    = (   0,   0,   0)                 # Define some colors using rgb values.  These can be

white    = ( 255, 255, 255)                 # used throughout the game instead of using rgb values.



# Define additional Functions and Procedures here
score = 0
bird = character()
blob = Enemy(random.randint(10,700),random.randint(10,400))
enemies = [blob]

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------

while done == False:



    for event in pygame.event.get():        # Check for an event (mouse click, key press)

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:       # If user clicked close window

            done = True                     # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

# Update sprites here
    for blob in enemies:
        blob.move_towards_player(bird)
        bird.collide(blob,enemies)
        blob.draw(screen)
    bird.movement()

    screen.blit(background_image,[0,0])

    bird.draw(screen)
    blob.draw(screen)



    pygame.display.update()                   # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.

    clock.tick(20)                        # Limit to 20 frames per second
    score += 1
pygame.quit()                               # Close the window and quit.
```

When I run the code, the blob (enemy) doesn't spawn, but when I take out the for enemy in enemies, which was suppose to be the collision, the blob spawns, and follows. I have tried many things for collision, but this is my first time creating a game in pygame, so I have to look everything up.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that sometimes your enemy just spawns directly next to the player, so a collision happens instantly. I don't know how the images you use look like, but make sure they are not too big with a lot of empty space, since your collision is not pixel perfect, but uses the entire size/rect of the image.

Otherwise, your code should work fine so far, but you could still improve it a bit. For example, since you already use the `Sprite` class for your `character`, you could also use the Group class to make your code a little simpler (drawing/moving/collision detection).

Here's how it could look like:

```
import pygame
import os,sys
import random
import math

img_path = os.path.join("punch.png")
img_blob = os.path.join("blob.png")

class Actor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Actor,self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([160,160])
        self.image.set_colorkey(black)
        self.image.blit(pygame.image.load(img_path),(0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.speed = 2

class Enemy(Actor):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
         super(Enemy, self).__init__(x, y)
         self.target = None

    def update(self, enemies):
        if self.target:
            dx,dy =  self.target.rect.x - self.rect.x,  self.target.rect.y - self.rect.y
            dist = math.hypot(dx,dy)
            dx,dy = dx / dist,dy / dist
            self.rect.x += dx * self.speed
            self.rect.y += dy * self.speed

class Character(Actor):

    def __init__(self, x = 275, y = 250):
        super(Character, self).__init__(x, y)
        self.speed = 10

    def update(self, enemies):

        pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, enemies, True)

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key[pygame.K_w]:
            self.rect.y -= self.speed
        elif key[pygame.K_s]:
            self.rect.y += self.speed
        if key[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rect.x -= self.speed
        elif key[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rect.x += self.speed

        if self.rect.x > 1110:
            self.rect.x = 1110

        if self.rect.y < 20:
            self.rect.y = 20

        elif self.rect.y > 710:
            self.rect.y = 710
        if self.rect.x <20:
            self.rect.x = 20
        elif self.rect.x == 1110 and self.rect.y > 300 and self.rect.y < 400:
            self.rect.x = 25
        if self.rect.y == 20 and self.rect.x >500 and self.rect.x < 600:
            self.rect.y = 715
        elif self.rect.x == 20 and self.rect.y > 300 and self.rect.y < 400:
            self.rect.x = 1090
        if self.rect.y == 710 and self.rect.x >500 and self.rect.x < 600:
            self.rect.y = 25


pygame.init()                               # Pygame is initialised (starts running)

players = pygame.sprite.Group()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1250,850]) # Set the width and height of the screen [width,height]
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")       # Name your window
background_image = pygame.image.load("untilted.png")

done = False                                # Loop until the user clicks the close button.

clock = pygame.time.Clock()                 # Used to manage how fast the screen updates
black    = (   0,   0,   0)                 # Define some colors using rgb values.  These can be
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)                 # used throughout the game instead of using rgb values.

# Define additional Functions and Procedures here
score = 0
bird = Character()
blob = Enemy(random.randint(500,700),random.randint(300,400))
blob.target=bird
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group([blob, bird])
enemies = pygame.sprite.Group([blob])

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while done == False:

    for event in pygame.event.get():        # Check for an event (mouse click, key press)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:       # If user clicked close window
            done = True                     # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

    screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))

    all_sprites.update(enemies)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()                   # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.

    clock.tick(20)                        # Limit to 20 frames per second
    score += 1
pygame.quit()
```

Note how the main loop only need to call `all_sprites.update` and  `all_sprites.draw`, and the rest is handled by the classes `Enemy` and `Character` themselves.